# deep link only works if the app is already running

Tags: android, flutter, routes, deep-linking, android-deep-link

If the app is already running, every time the deep link gets clicked it launches a new mainscreen on it and the corresponding video gets played but if the app is not running and the link is clicked then it launches the app but doesnt route it to the required mainscreen.

```
onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
        if (settings.name != null && settings.name!.startsWith('/')) {
          // Handle custom URLs
          return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => MainScreen(index: settings.name!.substring(1)),
          );
        }
        return null;
      },
    );
  }
}

class MainScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final String index;

  const MainScreen({Key? key, required this.index}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          FeedScreen(index: index),
          Positioned(
            top: 20,
            left: 16, // Adjust the left value to move it to the left
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.transparent, // Adjust the opacity here
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16),
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  'Timepass',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 24,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FeedScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String index;

  FeedScreen({Key? key, required this.index}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _FeedScreenState createState() => _FeedScreenState();
}

class _FeedScreenState extends State<FeedScreen> {
  late PageController _pageController;
  List<String> _videoUrls = [];
  List<int> _videoIndexes = [];
  late int _currentPage;
  late BannerAd _bannerAd;
  bool _isBannerAdReady = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _currentPage = int.tryParse(widget.index) ?? 0;
    _pageController =
        PageController(initialPage: _currentPage, viewportFraction: 1.0);
    if (widget.index.isNotEmpty) {
      fetchVideoUrlFromFirestore(int.parse(widget.index));
    } else {
      fetchVideoUrls();
    }
    _loadBannerAd();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _pageController.dispose();
    _bannerAd.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _onPageChanged(int page) {
    setState(() {
      _currentPage = page;
    });
  }

  void _onVideoEnded() {
    if (_currentPage < _videoUrls.length - 1) {
      _pageController.nextPage(
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
        curve: Curves.easeOut,
      );
    }
  }

  void fetchVideoUrls() async {
    final snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('videos')
        .doc('all_videos2')
        .get();
    final urls = snapshot.data()?['urls'] as List<dynamic>;

    final random = Random();
    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> videoList = [];

    for (int i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
      final videoMap = {
        'index': i,
        'url': urls[i],
      };
      videoList.add(videoMap);
    }

    videoList.shuffle(random);

    setState(() {
      _videoUrls = List<String>.from(videoList.map((video) => video['url'] as String));
      _videoIndexes = List<int>.from(videoList.map((video) => video['index'] as int));
    });
  }

  void fetchVideoUrlFromFirestore(int index) async {
    final snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('videos')
        .doc('all_videos2')
        .get();
    final urls = snapshot.data()?['urls'] as List<dynamic>;

    if (index >= 0 && index < urls.length) {
      final random = Random();
      final List<Map<String, dynamic>> videoList = [];

      for (int i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
        final videoMap = {
          'index': i,
          'url': urls[i],
        };
        videoList.add(videoMap);
      }

      videoList.shuffle(random);

      setState(() {
        _videoUrls = List<String>.from(videoList.map((video) => video['url'] as String));
        _videoIndexes = List<int>.from(videoList.map((video) => video['index'] as int));
        _videoUrls[0] = urls[index];
        _videoIndexes[0] = index;
      });
      _pageController.jumpToPage(0); // Jump to the first page when fetching a specific video
    }
  }
```

The fetchvideourl() is used when the user simply opens the app without any deeplink. fetchvideourlsfromfirestore() is used when the video have to be played via deeplink but it only works when the app is already running. If the app starts from scratch via deeplink fetchvideourl() is called and not fetchvideourlfromfirestore().

Comment: Deep links require changes in your Android Manifest for Android and your info.plist for iOS. Could you show those files? (hide any sensible info)